# Why use 'being' in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, present-participles

I came across this sentence in my programming book:

> There are a number of differences that need to be explained though,
>   the most important one being that read or write accesses to the file
>   performed by applications actually affect the target of the link and
>   not the link itself.

Why would it bother to use the following?

> ...the most important one is that read or write...

Answer (score 7):

*Being* allows the writer to continue the sentence. If you wanted to replace *the most important one being ...* with *the most important one is ...* you'd have to start a new sentence. That would probably be quite a good thing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Barrie that "being" is apparently used as a crutch for a run-on sentence, but I want to object to its stylistic merit. I dislike the passivity of gerunds in general, but I suppose they cannot always be avoided. In this example as applied to "to be", "being" seems presumptuous. I feel like the author is weasel-wording [couldn't avoid this one] reality.

Answer (score 0):

The author may not have bothered to explain at length his intention of focusing on the "number of differences" part, leaving "the most important" to a supporting role.

Replacing *being* with *is* completely shifts the focus to "the most important".

After reading the sentence, one is supposed to think "okay, so there are differences, including...".

In the suggested revision with *is*, the reader is left concluding: "I know what the most important difference is".

Makes a huge difference, right?